# How to Fault Hugepages in File Backed Shared Memory in Multiple-Writer Case

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-memory, huge-pages

I have multiple writers that will `mmap()` multiple shared (i.e. `MAP_SHARED` is specified) hugepages backed by a file.

Zeroing (e.g. `memset(ptr, 0, size)`) those hugepages can fault the pages in advance.

However, if I have multiple writers (multiple processes), probably only 1 writer should be zero-ing the pages when those pages are mapped the first time because this way, I don't have to worry about readers still reading or about writers still writing while a writer is zeroing out.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to fault pages in advance besides zeroing/writing to pages?
2. If no, what's the common way to fault pages without affecting the readers that are reading and the writers that are writing?

[`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) implies that `mlock()` could prefault the pages:

```
MAP_LOCKED (since Linux 2.5.37)
              Mark the mapped region to be locked in the same way as
              mlock(2).  This implementation will try to populate (prefault)
              the whole range but the mmap() call doesn't fail with ENOMEM
              if this fails.  Therefore major faults might happen later on.
              So the semantic is not as strong as mlock(2).  One should use
              mmap() plus mlock(2) when major faults are not acceptable
              after the initialization of the mapping.  The MAP_LOCKED flag
              is ignored in older kernels.
```

However, [`mlock(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) doesn't explicitly state that pages will be faulted when `mlock()` is called.  Thought?

Answer (score 1):

As for `mlock(2)`:

See [these](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4125/chap6mem-15/index.html) docs.

> References to locked pages in this process or in other processes do not result in page faults that require an I/O operation

As for your question

> 1. Is there a way to fault pages in advance besides zeroing/writing to pages?

Yes there is a "maybe" way. See [`posix_madivse(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_madvise.3.html)'s `POSIX_MADV_WILLNEED` flag.

Also see [`madvise(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) which is way more cooler than the above in terms of features but isn't specified by any standards.

Comment: Seems like both `posix_madivse()` and `madvise()` allows only a hint to the OS to fault the pages in advance but whether the pages are faulted is not guaranteed?

Comment: @HCSF right, check out [`mincore(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html), it may help you to get information about pages.